# How can I prove $\lim_{s\to 1^-}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^n\frac{\Gamma(1+ns)}{\Gamma(1+n)}=\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: asymptotics, special-functions

I find two interesting limits ([related post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/358626) on MO):
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}& =\lim_{s\to 1^-}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^n\frac{\Gamma(1+ns)}{\Gamma(1+n)}\\
& =\lim_{s\to 1^+}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^n\frac{\Gamma(1+n)}{\Gamma(1+ns)}.
\end{align*}
It's definition of $1-1+1-1+\cdots$ being **Le Roy summable**.

Further conjecture is
$$\underset{x\geqslant 0}{\sup}\left|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-x\right)^n}{\Gamma(1+\alpha n)}\right|=\begin{cases}
1& 0<\alpha\leqslant 2\\
+\infty& \alpha>2
\end{cases}.$$
If this conjecture is valid, I can apply Dominated Convergence Theorem to calculate the limits above.

I just used the **Corollary 3.7** of **Mittag-Leffler
Functions, Related Topics and Applications** to prove
$$\underset{x\geqslant 0}{\sup}\left|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-x\right)^n}{\Gamma(1+\alpha n)}\right|=\begin{cases}
\mathrm{finite}& 0<\alpha\leqslant 2\\
+\infty& \alpha>2
\end{cases}.$$
However, I have no idea to improve **finite** to **1**. Thanks for any help.

Comment: $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{\Gamma(1+ns)}{n!} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{ns}e^{-x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(x + x^s)}\,dx.$ Now let $s \to 1^{-}$ to see that the limit is $1/2$.

Comment: For the second one .. are you familiar with [Hankel's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_contour) for $\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}$? (the tags are too narrow here to understand what you are familiar with . )

Comment: @r9m Sorry, I just had a glance at it once. Thus I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 4):

Using the integral representation of the Gamma function we have for $0\le s<1$

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\Gamma(1+ns)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\int_0^\infty x^{ns}e^{-x}\,dx\tag1\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{ns}}{n!}\,dx\tag2\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}e^{-x^s}\,dx\\\\
\end{align}$$

Letting $s\to 1^-$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{s\to 1^-}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\Gamma(1+ns)&=\int_0^\infty e^{-2x}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac12
\end{align}$$

as expected!

---

> **NOTE:**
>
> In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$ we noted that $\left|\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{(-1)^nx^{ns}}{n!}\right|\le e^{x^s}$.   And $\int_0^\infty e^{-x}e^{x^s}\,dx<\infty$ for $0\le s<1$.  Application of the Dominated convergence theorem guarantees that the interchange of the series and integral is legitimate.

Comment: Thanks very much.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.